# How to supress hive warning

Tags: hive

I am new to Hive. Trying to execute one query which is outputing data to one file.

Below is my query :

> hive -e "SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;set
>   hive.server2.logging.operation.level=NONE;SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb
>   = 16384; SET mapreduce.map.java.opts='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx13107M';SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 13107; SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
>   -Xmx16384M';set hive.support.concurrency = false; SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;SET
>   hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict; SET
>   hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;SET
>   hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000; SET
>   hive.exec.max.created.files=1000000;SET
>   mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=128000000; SET
>   hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=true;set
>   hive.execution.engine=mr; set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;hive query
>   over here;" > /tmp/analysis

But in /tmp/analysis file i can see warnings as well as below.

WARN: The method class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory#release() was invoked.
WARN: Please see http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation.

How can i supress that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hive doc https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli

**Logging:**

Hive uses log4j for logging. By default logs are not emitted to the console by the CLI. **The default logging level is WARN for Hive releases prior to 0.13.0. Starting with Hive 0.13.0, the default logging level is INFO.** By default Hive will use `hive-log4j.default` in the `conf/` directory of the Hive installation which writes out logs to `/tmp/<userid>/hive.log` and uses the `WARN` level.

It is often desirable to emit the logs to the standard output and/or change the logging level for debugging purposes. These can be done from the command line as follows:

```
 $HIVE_HOME/bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

`hive.root.logger` specifies the logging level as well as the log destination. Specifying console as the target sends the logs to the standard error (instead of the log file).

If the user wishes, the logs can be emitted to the console by adding the arguments shown below:

```
bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console  //for HiveCLI (deprecated)
bin/hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Alternatively, the user can change the logging level only by using:

```
bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,DRFA //for HiveCLI (deprecated)
bin/hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,DRFA
```

Another option for logging is TimeBasedRollingPolicy (applicable for Hive 1.1.0 and above, HIVE-9001) by providing DAILY option as shown below:

```
bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,DAILY //for HiveCLI (deprecated)
bin/hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,DAILY
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use hive silent mode which doesn't print any logs in the output

```
hive -S -e "SET hive.auto.convert.join=false;set hive.server2.logging.operation.level=NONE;SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 16384; SET mapreduce.map.java.opts='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx13107M';SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = 13107; SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts='-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx16384M';set hive.support.concurrency = false; SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict; SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions=100000; SET hive.exec.max.created.files=1000000;SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=128000000; SET hive.hadoop.supports.splittable.combineinputformat=true;set hive.execution.engine=mr; set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;hive query over here;" > /tmp/analysis
```